# Linq to dataset on dynamic columns and dynamic group by fields

Tags: linq

I have four parameters to my function a dataset, array consisting of expressions (aggregate functions), array consisting of column names on which to apply expressions and an array consisting of columns on which I have to group by.

My problem is how can I handle dynamic columns or fields for expression and group by as it can vary in numbers (depends on array values).

I have written code for static query, but need a generic way...

This is my code:

```
public void ExpressionManipulation(DataSet dsExprEvaluate, string[] strExpressions, string[] colName, string[] groupbyFields)
{
        int groupByLength = groupbyFields.Length;

        var groupByQueryEvaluate = from table in dsExprEvaluate.AsEnumerable()
                          group table by new { column1 = table["DataSourceType"], column2 = table["Polarity"] }
                              into groupedTable
                              select new
                              {
                                  x = groupedTable.Key,  // Each Key contains column1 and column2
                                  y = groupedTable.Count(),
                                  //z = groupedTable.Max(column1),
                                  z = groupedTable.Sum(table => Convert.ToInt32(table["Polarity"]))
                              };
}
```

Like in above I can have n number of fields in group by like for now I have taken only two (DataSourceType and Polarity) and similar I can have n number of fields for expressions, for sum, count etc which will be as an array as parameter.

Please help me through this, it is driving me crazy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The column names and expression and fields on which to perform group by depends on user selection...

Comment: can anyone provide the solution or guidance????

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself and the solution i ended up is with:

```
var objGroupSumCountkey = dt.AsEnumerable()
                            .AsQueryable()
                            .GroupBy("new ( it[\"DataSourceType\"] as GroupByColumnName1,it[\"Polarity\"] as GroupByColumnName2)", "it")
                            .Select("new ( Sum(Convert.ToDouble(it[\"Polarity\"].ToString())) as SumValue,Count() as TotalCount,it.key)");
```

in the above query all the parameters will be supplied as string, in Group By and select